# Surface tension

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

Does surface tension force act lateral or perpendicular to the surface of liquid .
The formula of surface tension ;
Surface tension = Force/length
What does the parameter length mean,the perimeter,length of a side or what exactly

Comment: Consider looking through the discussions on this site as obtained from a search for `surface tension perpendicular`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Surface tension acts parallel to the surface. Imagine a straight line, L, in the surface. The surface (A) to one side of this line pulls the surface (B) to the other side of the line with a force $\vec F$, and B pulls A with a force $-\vec F$. These forces are directed parallel to the surface and at right angles to L. [I recommend you draw a diagram.]

The forces are of a magnitude proportional to the length, $l$, of L. [Equal lengths of line contribute equal force.]
We define the surface tension, $T$, as
$$T=\frac{|\vec F|}l$$
What about where the liquid surface meets a solid interruption, such as the sides of a vessel? The surface pulls at right angles on the line on the solid where the liquid meets it, exerting a force of magnitude $T$ per unit length on it.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Hope it cleared up your difficulties.

Comment: It would be great if u could also help with this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/755576/361933

Comment: I've written you a short answer.