# Surface tension in a bubble

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, bubbles

In a bubble or liquid droplet how is tangential surface tension force assumed to be balanced by perpendicular pressure force?

Answer (score 0):

The pull (tangential to the surface and at right angles to the equator) exerted across the drop's equator by the surface of one hemisphere, $\text{H}_2$, of the drop on the surface of the other hemisphere, $\text{H}_1$, will be of magnitude $2\pi r\ T$ and directed parallel to the line joining the poles of the sphere. For $\text{H}_1$ to be in equilibrium this pull must be balanced by the push, $\pi r^2p$, acting across the equatorial plane, of the interior pressure. This force is in the opposite direction to the surface tension force. Hence the familiar result, $p=2T/r$, for the equilibrium pressure inside the drop. [Inside a *bubble* the pressure is $p=4T/r$; can you see why?]

There are several ways of deriving this result.

Comment: I understand this ,but is the pull and push lateral ,or perpendicular to the surface of hemisphere?.

Comment: My question follows along the line that presure force act perpendicularly to an area,the surface tension force i modelled on the hemisphere acts perpendicularly to the pressure force so how do they balance each other

Comment: Consider the forces on one of the hemispheres, H$_1$. The surface tension pull is tangential to the surface and at right angles to the equator all the way round the equator. So this pull is parallel to the axis of the sphere through its poles. The force, $\pi r^2 p$, on H$_1$, due to the pressure that the liquid is under, acts all across the equatorial plane of the sphere and acts at right angles to that plane, so is also parallel to the axis of the sphere through its poles, but in the opposite direction from the surface tension force. [Choice of equator and associated poles is arbitrary.]

Comment: "the surface tension force i modelled on the hemisphere acts perpendicularly to the pressure force" This is so at any given point on the surface, but you need to consider a larger portion. Suggest you re-read my previous (long) comment very carefully. Note that I'm considering the equilibrium of a complete hemisphere, including both its surface and the fluid inside it. That's why I take the force on it due to the fluid to act across the equatorial plane and therefore to be parallel to the axis that runs between the poles of the sphere.